# Overwrite file from svn:externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using svn:externals to include code from another project - for which I do not want to commit changes to.

One of the files included by svn:externals needs a small change (just a line) to work with my current project. So I want to commit this to my own SVN.

How do I do this? If I try and commit as things are now, it tries to commit my changes to this file to the owners SVN - which obviously isn't possible.

Should be easy I guess? I'm using TortoiseSVN on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need a [vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html). That is, copy the external to your own repo, make your changes and periodically update the copy.